# Integrate custom tax and discounts in Stripe checkout session

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Can you please help me with integration of tax and discounts in my Stripe sission

This is my current code

```
class CreateCheckoutSessionOrderView(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    order_id = self.kwargs["order_id"]
    DOMAIN: str = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    # tax_rates = []
    # for tax in order.tax.all():
    #     tax_rate = stripe.TaxRate.create(
    #         display_name=tax.name,
    #         description=tax.name,
    #         percentage=tax.rate,
    #         jurisdiction="RU",
    #         inclusive=False,
    #     )
    #     tax_rates.append(tax_rate.id)
    #
    # discounts = []
    # for discount in order.discount.all():
    #     discount_amount = stripe.Coupon.create(
    #         amount_off=discount.amount,
    #         duration='once',
    #         currency='usd',
    #         name=discount.name,
    #     )
    #     discounts.append(discount_amount.id)

    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'unit_amount': order.get_total_cost() * 100,
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': order.__str__(),
                    },
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            },

        ],
        payment_intent_data={
            'metadata': {
                'order_id': order.id,
            },
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url=DOMAIN + '/success/',
        cancel_url=DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
        # tax_rates=tax_rates,
        discounts=[{"discounts": '{{COUPON_ID}}'}],
    )
    return JsonResponse({'id': session.id})
```

Getting this traceback for now

```
stripe._error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_h7p3k0OElRSyeg: Received unknown parameter: discounts[0][discounts]
[07/Jan/2024 10:40:53] "GET /order_checkout/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 115336
```

I really appreciate any suggestions and code review. I'm just learning how to deal with stripe payments for now

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with Stripe API, but looking at the error, I can say that there is a difference between the `discounts[0][discounts]` received in the callback and the `discounts=[{"discounts": '{{COUPON_ID}}'}]` you wrote.

I think you should change the `discounts=[{"discounts": '{{COUPON_ID}}'}]` value to `discounts=[array_len][{"discounts": '{{COUPON_ID}}'}]`. I guess the `array_len` I added here may be the number of discounts.

As I said, I may not have provided a complete solution since I do not work with Stripe API.